# Using .shadow() with cypress.io in github actions

Tags: reactjs, cypress, github-actions

I'm writing some e2e tests in React using Cypress. I get it all to work fine in my local dev environment, but when the test runs in the GitHub Action pipeline it fails.

I think this is because I am trying to access shadow Dom elements and that is not working for some reason when running the action.

This is my test:

```
it('Should be able to click add to list button',
    { includeShadowDom: true },
    () => {
        cy.get('.IPEX_HSD_product_sheet_add_to_bag')
        .shadow()
        .find('kompis-icon-button', { includeShadowDom: true })
        .shadow()
        .find('button')
        .click();
    }
);
```

This is my cypress configuration:

```
{
    "baseUrl": "http://127.0.0.1:3000/#/",
    "includeShadowDom": true,
    "defaultCommandTimeout": 10000,
    "fixturesFolder": false,
    "integrationFolder": "./test/e2e",
    "pluginsFile": false,
    "supportFile": "./test/cypress.support.ts",
    "testFiles": "**/*.test.ts",
    "video": false
}
```

These are the scripts in my package.json:

```
"cypress:open": "cypress open --config-file ./test/cypress.config.json",
"test:e2e": "cypress run --headed --config-file ./test/cypress.config.json",
"test:e2e:ci": "start-server-and-test serve http://localhost:3000 test:e2e"
```

This is from my workflow.yml:

```
  - name: Install dependencies and cache them. Run E2E tests against production build 
    uses: cypress-io/github-action@v2
    with:
      build: npm run build
      start: npm start
      command: npm run test:e2e:ci
      cache-key: node-modules-${{ hashFiles('package-lock.json') }}
```

As you can see I have added includeShadowDom: true wherever it has been possible, but it seems to have no effect.

The error I am getting is:

```
AssertionError: Timed out retrying after 10000ms: Expected to find element: `kompis-icon-button`, but never found it. Queried from element: <kompis-add-to-bag.IPEX_HSD_product_sheet_add_to_bag>
```

This is the source HTML:

[image: The source HTML]

Comment: Can you add the html of the element ?

Comment: @AlapanDas yes, I have added it.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming that you have added `"includeShadowDom": true,` in your `cypress.json`, then you don't need to add `shadow()` anywhere else. `cy.get()` will automatically traverse through shadow dom.

```js
cy.get('.IPEX_HSD_product_sheet_add_to_bag', {timeout: 7000})
  .should('be.visible')
  .find('kompis-button > button', {timeout: 7000})
  .click()
```

Comment: Thank you, but I have tried that, and it works fine locally, but as soon as I run it through a git action, the test breaks.

Comment: You can add an visible assertion.

Comment: Thanks again, but I'm pretty sure that my test syntax is okay. My problem is what happens in the git action pipeline and why it cannot seem to find the shadow elements there.

Comment: Can you check whether your application is loading the same way in git action as it does in local ? Because I cannot see any other reason why your code shouldn’t work if it is successful in local.

Comment: I'd love to, but how do I do that?

Comment: You can take screenshots and add it to artifacts for debugging.